# ASP.NET : my html element repeated after my postback finish

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have an asp web page and my page contains to RadCombobox. for first drop down i set item_requested method (when the user click on it and select the theater name.it has a post back and after post back the second drop down fill with sans numbers ).
my problem is here:
after page post back the second field set duplicate in my page. in these pictures you can see that.
Before post back:
[image]

the second image :(After postback the second fielset repeated)
[image]

**Note**:
all of my controls in update panel. after i remove update panel from my page i doesn't happen again.Do you know the reason ? :[

Comment: You might be adding components from code and when it's a postback it gets added again, as you know Update Panel, does partial postback, but it's a postback.

So put condition to check request is postback or not.

Comment: i don't get it , can you describe it for me?

Comment: are you adding textbox via code?

Comment: no.all of elements are static and none of them in code behind. i just fill first drop down in code behind and in my page load i just check Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and admin Access. just this. i don't know why my field set duplicate in my page :(

Comment: then you got to share some code here, as it might be possible there is some unwanted code in your coding practice which is creating this issue.

Comment: page load :if (!IsPostBack){int sid = 0; string  sql ="";cnn.Open();
string result = BaseFunctions.ExecuteCommand(cnn, "select id from adminaccess where username='"  + Page.User.Identity.Name;+ "'", true);if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || result == null){Response.Redirect("home.aspx");}

Comment: this code doesn't look to have any issues.
Probably something around your updatepanel, did you try removing Update panel?

Comment: i remove the second field set from update panel and it works true. but i don't understand the reason.   thank you for reason :)

Comment: cool, probably happening because when that particular panel is updated its a postback and html is getting rendered twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some logic where you are adding this component. Try to check IsPostBack before adding the component to the page. Just like that:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
    //dynamically add component
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reason , but i use this in code behind. but it doesn't work again:(

Comment: page load :if (!IsPostBack){int sid = 0; string sql ="";cnn.Open(); string result = BaseFunctions.ExecuteCommand(cnn, "select id from adminaccess where username='" + Page.User.Identity.Name;+ "'", true);if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || result == null){Response.Redirect("home.aspx");}

Answer (score 0):

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // ASPX C#
        }
    }
```

ASP
................... IM NOT GOOD AT ASP

Comment: Can you please reformat your answer and update it with some more information? Please refer to [this FAQ on how to answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.